# Is my data being corrupted due to multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, streaming, rendering

I am using a local server/client setup to test a point rendering program I have written. The client receives data points from the server correctly, however due to the high volume of data points that need to be processed, I have used the `System.Threading.Tasks` library to employ multithreading to process the data faster.

[The output of the program should look like this (which currently takes an hour to process):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6yPi.png)

[However, when using my multithreaded solution, it comes out like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcTP9.png)

The code I have used to setup the multithreading is below (initialisation and such is taken care of above the sample).

```
void Update () {
    //Read bytes data from server stream
    length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    if(length != 0){    

        // Convert byte array to string message
        startedStreaming = true;
        finishedStreaming = false;
        serverMessage += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); 
    }

    else{
        finishedStreaming = true;
    }

    if(startedStreaming == true && finishedStreaming == true){
        startedStreaming = false;
        rendered = false;
        readyToProcess = false;
        StartCoroutine(DataStreaming());
    }
    if(readyToRender == true && rendered == false){
        rendered = true;
        Debug.Log("Rendering");
        pcloud.updateBuffer();
    }
}



private IEnumerator DataStreaming(){   

    //Convert bytes data to readable strings once finished receiving
    if(finishedStreaming == true && readyToProcess == false){

        if(renderer.enabled == false){
            renderer.enabled = true;
        }

        newVectors = serverMessage.Split(new char[]{'\n'} );

        Debug.Log("Message split");

        pcloud._pointData =  new PointCloudData.Point[newVectors.Length];

        readyToProcess = true;
    }

    //Convert strings into numerical values and render once finished
    if(readyToProcess == true && readyToRender == false){
        readyToRender = true;
        Debug.Log("rendering, "+ Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
        Parallel.For(0, newVectors.Length, (coord) =>{
            row = newVectors[coord].Split(new char[]{','});
            float x = int.Parse(row[0]);
            float y = int.Parse(row[1]);
            float z = int.Parse(row[2]);

            pcloud._pointData[coord].position = new Vector3((float)(x/pixelsPerUnit), (float)(y/1000f), (float)(z/pixelsPerUnit));

            pcloud._pointData[coord].color = Pcx.PointCloudData.EncodeColor(dict[(int)y]); 
        });
    }

    if(readyToRender ==  true){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    }
}
```

I am assuming that the mutlithreading is corrupting the data in some way. Is there anything I need to change or fix to get the correct result?

Comment: I think that is happening because your local server does not support multithreading. Similar to when your export Unity model to WebGL if your model has multithreading it will not run cause browsers browsers do not support multithreading due to security issues

Comment: The multithreading is only being used for the rendering part of the program; the app won't be run in a browser so that won't be an issue.

Comment: if you are trying to use threads with any of the Unity methods or object, it will cause a lot of problems. You can for example make multithreaded list sorting, but you can't use multithread with Unity Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a try-catch loop and discovered that a single line of corrupt data was the source of the problem. This appears to be due to the server-socket part of the program and so I won't discuss it further here, but the try-catch loop was a great solution to find where the problem was occurring, and to allow the program to continue despite errors occurring.